# Changing ng-repeat variable with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom `ngRepeat` directive that should execute ***before*** the original `ngRepeat` directive. In there I then want to change the original attribute `ng-repeat="user in users"` to something like `ng-repeat="user in $data"`.

I then expect that the original `ngRepeat` would not show any data since `$data` has no items. But this is not happening. It still displays all the data.

Take a look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/uHTJ61aA7drcg6ZVjNbj?p=preview

In there you can see that my directive changes the `ng-repeat` attribute. If you check the HTML with the dev tool then you can see that it is changed to `ng-repeat="user in $data"`.

How come it's then still able render all the rows? How can I prevent that from happening?

---

Actually I want to fill `$data` with just a small portion of what's in `$scope.users`. Therefor I have to intercept the original `user in users` with my custom `user in $data` attribute.

Comment: Why don't you just set `$data` to the small portion of users on `$scope` and use that?  Note that you can't override built in directives

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm not in control of what's happening in any controller. I'm actually trying to create a module for a HTML `<table>`. I have to read what's in the `ng-repeat` attrib and replace that with something else so my module knows what to look for. That's why I want to change `someVar in someArray` to `someVar in $data`. The directive in my module will then have control over `$scope.$data`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there are 2 solutions, both of them different from your current approach. (And probably easier to implement and maintain)

1) Filter the data in the controller and expose the variable with the filtered items in the scope to the original ng-repeat - you can then switch between full or filtered data in your controller by changing the content of the variable that you expose in the scope.

2) You could also use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) as part of your "user in data" part, like "user in data | filter:search".

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following. I don't think this is an option for me because I'm creating an angular module for a HTML `<table>`. I'm not in control of what is happening in any controller. Since other people will make use of my module. So everything should go through the directive in my module.

Comment: @Vivendi So what is your use-case? If you want to override behavior but people will have to actively include your solution you should also be able to specify your own attribute instead of trying to override an existing one. Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: @Vivendi ... and option 2 doesn't require you to change anything in the controller.